# how to display the uploaded document as thumbnail in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have uploaded some documents and then after submit i am calling some service,
then i am getting those documents in the form of some URLs in the response as below,

```
{
"documents": [{
    "contentURL": "http://someexample1url",
    "format": "xls",
    "createdt": "12/27/2016"
}, {
    "contentURL": "http://someexample2url",
    "format": "doc",
    "createdt": "12/27/2016"
}, {
    "contentURL": "http://someexample2url",
    "format": "doc",
    "createdt": "12/27/2016"
}]
}
```

Below is my Jquery Code,

```
function handleFileSelect(documents) {
    var files = documents[0].contentURL;
    var f = files;
    var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = (function(files) {
            return function(e) {
              $("#some_id").html('<img src='+files+' width="50"/>');
            }
      })(f);

      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
   }
```

I am not sure where i am going wrong and finding it bit difficult to figure out.
Please help me with this.Different idea will also help me.

Comment: something else you may consider is converting the JSON string to actual JSON: var xdocs = JSON.parse(documents); then use xdocs for the rest of the steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function previewFile() {
  var preview = document.querySelector('img');
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function () {
    preview.src = reader.result;
  }

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  } else {
    preview.src = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>
<img src="" height="50" alt="">
```

Comment: in this we can only create thumbnail if it is image type but for documents i wont show any thumbnail as such. So is there any way we can show a thumbnail for that

Comment: And also i want to use the Url from the response i mentioned, not from the upload button

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to remove double quotes from files variables

   function handleFileSelect(documents) {
            var files = documents[0].contentURL;
            var f = files;
            var reader = new FileReader();

              reader.onload = (function(files) {
                    return function(e) {
                      $("#some_id").html('<img src='+files+' width="50" >');
                    }
              })(f);

              reader.readAsDataURL(f);
           }
```